# How to fix border margin in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to set a style for `Heading 1` to have a border around the text. I set my border in

```
Modify Style -> Format -> Border...
```

Unfortunately, for an unknown reason, the border crosses the page margins as shown here:

[image]

If I try to manually move the border, I can only extend it and once done it is not possible to move it back to its original size. If I release the mouse button on the following situation, the border will not get resized.

[image]

How to create a border around a text that fits the page margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default your paragraph may use the whole width between margins, and border is drawn AROUND the paragraph.

To keep the border within the margin you need to limit width of the paragraph.

By default border is placed 4 pts from text to left and right, and it has 1/2 pt width:
[image]

So you need to add 4.5 pt left and right indent (in Modify style - format - paragraph):
[image]